# An airflow task with all_success trigger rule ran even though there were failures before it

Tags: airflow

In the screenshot, you can see that the `update_checkpoint` task has run successfully; however, its `trigger_rule` was `all_success`, and we had failures in `RBS_wave_1` and `RBS_wave_3` task groups.
[image]

`RBS_wave` task groups are set to run sequentially, and their `trigger_rule` is `all_done`.
I'm not sure what I'm missing in setting up the `trigger_rule` for `update_checkpoint`. I want `update_checkpoint` to run only if all sequentially executed `RBS_wave` task groups are successfully executed.

Thank you :)

Comment: why all_done on RBS_wave, what if you set it to all_success ?

Comment: do you have dependency on all RBS tasks or only on the latest which is successful ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I need `RBS_wave` tasks to run even if something fails upstream, but the checkpoints should not be updated unless failure are addressed.

Comment: @kakou I thought I had set the dependency of `updated_checkpoints` on all previous tasks when I set its `trigger_rule` to `all_success`. If that's not true, how can I set the `trigger_rule` for `update_checkpoints` such that its execution depends on success of all the sequentially executed tasks prior to it?

Answer (score 0):

I m replying here since I would like some images in an attempt to explain.

If I am getting it correctly from the grid view your DAG in graph will look something like this:

[image]

That means that the actual dependency of the last task is on the `dummy_4` in this example and not in all the previous tasks together.

I assume something like this will be the dependency declaration:

```
dummy_1 >> dummy_2 >> dummy_3 >> destined_to_failed >> dummy_4 >> needs_to_run_when_all_succeed
```

In this scenario the `needs_to_run_when_all_succeed` will not run only on the case that its previous task fails:
[image]

```
dummy_1  >> dummy_2 >> dummy_3  >> dummy_4 >>  destined_to_failed >> needs_to_run_when_all_succeed
```

The simplest approach -which i am not aware if that suits you- would be to run the rest of the tasks in parallel and create a dependency on this block.

Meaning to do something like this:
[image]

With this setup:

```
[dummy_1, dummy_2, dummy_3, dummy_4,  destined_to_failed] >> needs_to_run_when_all_succeed
```

If that is not possible, a potential approach would be to use`XCOM` to store the state of each Task Group and check those states before starting the  `update_checkpoints` task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot run the tasks in parallel because that puts too much pressure on my compute resources. I'll look into the `XCOM` solution.